# u'https' is not a registered namespace

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-admin, django-views

I am trying to set the form action url dynamically from the server,

this is what the view action returns,

```
return render_to_response('filebrowser/form.html', {
        'posturl': posturl,
}, context_instance=Context(request))
```

and the posturl can have two values

1. this is the registered app url like www.example.com/upload
2. this is the other url which is youtube upload url which is like

   ```
   https://uploads.gdata.youtube.com/.........
   ```

while rendering the form itself if the posturl value is 1 its working fine, but if the value is second option then i am getting the error:

```
      Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
      Exception Value:  u'https' is not a registered namespace
```

but in case if i am rendering entire html with action from server its working fine,

like

```
  form = "<form action=posturl><form>"
  return HttpResponse(form)
```

any help would be appreciated,

How i used posturl in template.
i am using uploadify for upload.

```
   jQuery(function($) {    
    $('#id_file').uploadify({
        .....
        'script'            : '{% url posturl%}',
        ....
    });
please avoid any syntax errors
```

thanks

Comment: why is it down voted ?

Comment: +1 for the question. Please show how do you use `posturl` in the template. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @alecxe, thanks for your reply i have edited the question for how i used the posturl variable its basically a url tag.

Comment: just get rid of the url tag and you should be fine

Comment: thats great.. it worked, if you can put it as an answer i can accept it. also just curious on why that error was coming with url tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag doesn't handle external urls, it was designed to make a url from the view function and optional parameters. Just don't use `url` tag in this case.